# why is webgl mix inconsistent on some platforms and how can I fix it?

Tags: glsl, webgl, cross-platform

So after fiddling with Game Maker, then XNA, then C# DirectX, then C++ DirectX, then C++ OpenGL and Java OpenGL, I've come to HTML5/Javascript WebGL.

Everything seems to be working with a single exception, mix the predefined shader function is inconsistent cross-platform.

Out of my tested platforms, 2 Windows PC's (AMD drivers + chrome/ nVidia drivers + chrome), a galaxy tab 2 again using chroem and a HTC One using chrome, the PC's and tab 2 all compile as "mix(Start, End, Delta)" but the HTC One for reasons unknown to me compiles it as "mix(End, Start, Delta)"

I understand webgl implementations are browser and machine specific, but this is quite a strange difference, I believe the HTC One is the only machine running webgl as es 1.0 as opposed to es 2.0, but I'm not sure if that would be causing this behavior.

In any case the question remains, how would I go about fixing this to work consistently over multiple platforms?

Comment: Here's the conformance tests 4 mix [one](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/functions/glsl-function-mix-float.html?webglVersion=1), [two](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/glsl/functions/glsl-function-mix-gentype.html?webglVersion=1), [three](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/ogles/GL/mix/mix_001_to_006.html?webglVersion=1). If those work on ur HTC One then I'd suspect your code first but otherwise file bugs and bring it up on the [WebGL Public mailing list](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/)

Comment: Oh and BTW you can't run WebGL as ES1.0. ES1.0 has no shaders